# Show me new questions since my last visit?

Tags: feature-request

Some SE (ex: Gaming) question counts/flow rates are still pretty low, which makes me want to read ***all*** the new questions and hope I can help someone. Is there a way to **show questions new since my last visit**? If not can we add this feature?

Comment: I'll be honest I'm kind of confused by the current status of this question. I have one answer that doesn't answer my question, and even a comment by Mr. Atwood... that doesn't answer my question either, yet both have received up votes... It's like if I asked you if this city was going ever build a **subway** and you started telling me *how to take taxis* and then congratulated each other for it. They're not the same you know! Even a "no, we don't plan on ever implementing that" would be better resolution than I have now...

Comment: related question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22275/label-contents-as-new-since-we-last-logged-in

Answer (score 1):

This would actually be a very good idea. Some other Q&A sites (e.g. https://root-forum.cern.ch/) show a small separation line for questions active since your last visit.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can have all new questions sent  to your email every day by creating a [new filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters):

> [image]

No need to even visit the site.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to the bottom of the front page there is a link to *"Browse the complete list of questions"*, and once there you'll find a "newest" tab.

It doesn't keep track of when you were last around, however.

Comment: clicking "questions" at the top of the page does the same thing

Comment: I'm well familiar with the Newest list. But I was hoping for having questions clearly marked as **new since my last visit**. SE tracks my visits, obviously, so the datapoint is already in the system.